Laravel Eloquent Query WithCount on relation
I have the following simplified tables.
Basically, there are the User table, the Game table, and the Player table. Each user can join games and these are saved in the Player table.
User



Id
Name




1
James


2
Peter


3
Mary


4
Casey


5
Cindy



Game
User_Id is the host



Id
Title
User_Id




1
Game One
4


2
Game Two
4


3
Game Three
4


4
Game Four
5



Player
User_Id is the user who joins a game.
A player can join multiple games



Id
User_Id
Game_Id
Updated_At




1
1
1
2024-01-01 10:05:00


2
1
3
2024-01-01 10:07:00


3
2
1
2024-01-02 11:15:13


4
1
2
2024-01-03 12:05:22


5
1
4
2024-02-05 12:05:22



I am using the following to get a list of players who have joined the currently logged in user's game, sorted by joined dates in descending order.
$latest_joined_players = Player::with('user', 'game')
                ->WhereRelation('game', 'user_id', '=', $logged_in_user->id)
                ->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
                ->paginate(20);

Now, my question is. How do I also get:

The player's game count? In other words, how many games the player has joined the currently logged in user's (the host's) games?

The player's total game count? In other words, how many games the player has joined in total (regardless of the host)?


Assuming, logged_in_user = 4, expected result in summary, should be as following:



User_Id
Joined_Game_Count
Total_Joined_Game_Count
Joined_Date




1
3
4
2024-01-03 12:05:22


2
1
1
2024-01-02 11:15:13


1
3
4
2024-01-01 10:07:00


1
3
4
2024-01-01 10:05:00



Any help is much appreciated.

Why the user with id 1 is duplicated in your example?

You mean in the Player table? The User_Id in this table, is the user who joined the games. A player can join multiple games.

no i am talking about your result summary, you want the count of games that a user joined for a given host and a total games joined all the time, if that is the case why user with id of 1 is duplicated in result summary (your last table)

Oh, because I primarily need the list of users joining, sorted by the joining date and time.
